# Get absolute path of file OS X

Tags: bash, osx, pipe, echo

I am creating a script which will prompt the user to enter a location of file and it will convert it to an absolute path.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure how to append these together.

**absolute.sh**

```
read -e -p "Enter a path to a file: " PATH
CONVERTPATH="$(pwd $PATH)" "/" "$(basename $PATH)"
echo Absolute path is $CONVERTPATH
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *appending*, all you need do is get rid of the extra quotes, e.g., change

```
CONVERTPATH="$(pwd $PATH)" "/" "$(basename $PATH)"
```

to

```
CONVERTPATH="$(pwd $PATH)/$(basename $PATH)"
```

But there are a few problems:

- `pwd` does not take an argument; you can use `dirname` in the case presented.
- the `read` command will not set `PATH`; rename it, e.g., to `name`
- the `echo` command is incompletely quoted

With *those* fixes, you would have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter a path to a file: " name
CONVERTPATH="$(dirname $name)/$(basename $name)"
echo "Absolute path is $CONVERTPATH"
```

It does not handle the case where someone replies to the prompt with a variable.  Also, the intended use of `pwd` was likely to get the absolute directory.  You can try that by a further substitution

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Enter a path to a file: " name
head=$(dirname "$name")
head=$(cd "$head" && pwd)
CONVERTPATH="$head/$(basename $name)"
echo "Absolute path is $CONVERTPATH"
```

However, it still will not do what you *want*.  The problem (from your point of view) is that `pwd` on OSX will simply echo the result based on following any symbolic link from the `cd` command. This is not merely an OSX quirk, but longstanding Unix behavior which for instance allowed you to `cd` into a directory where you had no permissions to do a proper `pwd` by following up the chain of `..` entries.

If you want an absolute pathname which does not have any symbolic links in its result, you need a different approach.  OSX has [`realpath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/realpath.3.html) — but not on the command-line.  On some other systems, you could use [`readlink -f`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html), but not here.

For general discussion on this topic:

- [How can I retrieve the absolute filename in a shell script on Mac OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40144/how-can-i-retrieve-the-absolute-filename-in-a-shell-script-on-mac-os-x)
- [Bash script absolute path with OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572030/bash-script-absolute-path-with-osx)
- [Programatically retrieving the absolute path of an OS X command-line app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799679/programatically-retrieving-the-absolute-path-of-an-os-x-command-line-app)
- [How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the resources and examples :)

Comment: On almost any Linux distro `realpath myfile` always _print the resolved absolute file name_.

Comment: The question is asking about Mac.  `realpath .` on my Mac says "command not found"